# Tuning Navigation - robot keeps rotating when close to its goal

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My robot Mojo and I are happily trying to use the navigation stack.

After a bit of parameter tuning, I managed to get it follow its planned path quite well.

My only problem is that things get pretty rotational when Mojo closes on its goal.
As you can see in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oqTk4VZssg), it is like if it forgets it can also **not** move forward while rotating. Mojo is fitted with a differential drive.

I tried to play with some parameters of the base planner, but I can't really figure out how to stop this annoying rotation.
This is not my first experience with the navigation stack and I know it is possible to reach the goal far better than that.

Has anyone ever experienced this behaviour? How could I make it stop?

Here are my base planner parameters:

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.45
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  
  max_rotational_vel: 0.5
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.1

  acc_lim_th: 0.25
  acc_lim_x: 0.5
  
  vx_samples: 5                       #default is 3, I feel like putting 5. I'm the architect after all! :)
  vtheta_samples: 20                  #default is 20
  
  holonomic_robot: false
  
  path_distance_bias: 5.0             #default .6
  goal_distance_bias: 0.8             #default .8
  occdist_scale: 0.01                 #default 0.01
  
  heading_lookahead: 0.325            #default 0.325m   
  heading_scoring: false              #default false
  heading_scoring_timestep: 5.0       #default 0.8 sec
  
  sim_time: 5.0                       #default is 1.0 - simulate 5 seconds ahead
  sim_granularity: 0.025              #default is 0.025 - simulation with steps of 2.5 cm
 
  dwa: false                          #I prefer trajectory rollout as I can see it in rviz
  
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2              #default is 10cm but I think AMCL makes it too giggly for this to be safe
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.09            #default is 0.05 rad (~3 degrees), I changed it to 5
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9795/tuning-navigation---robot-keeps-rotating-when-close-to-its-goal/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-04-21

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Note: As suggested, this guide has now moved to the ROS wiki. For an up-to-date version of the navigation tuning guide please see the [Navigation Tuning Guide Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide).**

Ok. First off, I'll answer the question about turning at a really low angular speed. This is just a bug which should be fixed in the next patch release of navigation. There's a ticket to track it here: https://kforge.ros.org/navigation/trac/ticket/2.

As for the broader question of how to tune the navigation stack, I'll do my best below to outline how I typically go about things. With that said, its a bit different for every robot. So, with no further ado, basic navigation tuning:

### Basic Navigation Tuning Guide

This guide seeks to give some standard advice on how to tune the [ROS Navigation Stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation) on a robot. This guide is in no way comprehensive, but should give some insight into the process. I'd also encourage folks to make sure they've read the [ROS Navigation Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) before this post as it gives a good overview on setting the navigation stack up on a robot wheras this guide just gives advice on the process.

### Step 1: Is the robot navigation ready?

The large majority of the problems I run into when tuning the navigation stack on a new robot lie in areas outside of tuning parameters on the local planner. Things are often wrong with the odometry of the robot, localization, sensors, and other pre-requisites for running navigation effectively. So, the first thing I do is to make sure that the robot itself is navigation ready. This consists of three component checks: range sensors, odometry, and localization.

#### Range Sensors

If the robot isn't getting information from its range sensors, such as lasers, then nothing with navigation will work. I'll make sure that I can view sensor information in rviz, that it looks relatively correct, and that its coming in at the expected rate.

#### Odometry

Often, I'll have a lot of trouble getting a robot to localize correctly. It will constantly get lost and I'll spend a lot of time mucking with the parameters for [AMCL](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl) only to find that the real culprit is the robot's odometry. As such, I always run two sanity checks to make sure that I believe the odometry of a robot.

The first test checks how reasonable the odometry is for rotation. I open up rviz, set the frame to "odom," display the laser scan the robot provides, set the decay time on that topic high (something like 20 seconds), and perform an in-place rotation. Then, I look at how closely the scans match each other on subsequent rotations. Ideally, the scans will fall right on top of each other, but some rotational drift is expected, so I just make sure that the scans aren't off by more than a degree or two.

The next test is a sanity check on odometry for translation. I'll set up rviz the same way with the robot a few meters away from a wall. Then, I'll drive the robot straight at the wall and look at the thickness of the wall as reported by the aggregated laser scans in rviz. Ideally, the wall should look like a single scan but I just make sure that it doesn't have a thickness of more than a few centimeters. If you drive a meter towards a wall and get scans spread out over half a meter though, something is likely wrong with the odometry.

#### Localization

Assuming that both odometry and a laser scanner are performing reasonably, making a map and tuning [AMCL](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl) normally isn't too bad. First, I'll run either [gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping) or [karto](http://www.ros.org/wiki/karto) and joystick the robot around to generate a map. Then, I'll use that map with AMCL and make sure that the robot stays localized. If the odometry for the robot that I'm running on isn't very good, I'll play around a bit with the [odometry model parameters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl#Parameters) for AMCL. A good test for the whole system is to make sure that laser scans and the map can be visualized in the "map" frame in rviz and that the laser scans match up well with the map of the enviroment.

### Step 2: The Costmap

Once I'm satisfied that the robot satisfies the prerequisites for navigation, I like to make sure that the costmap is setup and configured properly. I'll leave details on how to configure things for the costmap to the [ROS Navigation Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) and [costmap_2d documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d), but I'll give some tips on the things that I often do. Some things that I find useful for tuning the costmap:

- Make sure to set the `expected_update_rate` parameter for each observation source based on the rate at which the sensor actually publishes. I normally give a fair amount of tolerance here, putting the period for the check at twice what I'd expect, but its nice to receive warnings from navigation when a sensor falls way below its expected rate.
- Set the `transform_tolerance` parameter appropriately for the system. Its nice to check what the expected latency is for a transform from the "base_link" frame to the "map" frame using tf. I typically use [tf_monitor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#tf_monitor) to look at the delay for the system and set the parameter conservatively off of that. Also, if the delay reported by tf_monitor is sufficiently large, I might poke around a bit to see what's causing the latency. This sometimes leads me to find issues with how transforms are being published for a given robot.
- On robots that lack processing power, I'll consider turning down the `map_update_rate` parameter. When doing this, however, I take into account the fact that this will cause a delay in how quickly sensor data makes it into the costmap which, in turn, slows the speed at which the robot reacts to obstacles.
- The `publish_frequency` parameter is useful for visualizing the costmap in rviz. However, especially for large global maps, the parameter can cause things to run slowly. In production systems, I consider turning down the rate at which the costmap is published and when I need to visualize very large maps, I make sure to set the rate really low.
- The decision on whether to use the `voxel_grid` or `costmap` model for the costmap depends largely on the sensor suite that the robot has. Tuning the costmap for a 3D-based costmap is more involved as considerations about unknown space really come into play. If the robot I'm using just has a planar laser, I always use the `costmap` model for the map.
- Sometimes, its useful to be able to run navigation solely in the odometric frame. To do this, I find the easiest thing to do is to copy my `local_costmap_params.yaml` file over my `global_costmap_params.yaml` file and change the the `width` and `height` of the map to be something more like 10 meters. This is a really easy way to get things up and running if you want to tune navigation independent of localization performance.
- I tend to pick the resolution of the maps that I'm using based on the robot's size and processing ability. On a robot that has a lot of processing power and needs to fit through narrow spaces, like the PR2, I'll use a fine-grained map... setting the resolution to something like 0.025 meters. For something like a roomba, I might go as high as 0.1 meters in resolution to reduce the computational load.
- [Rviz](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz) is a great way to verify that the costmap is working correctly. I typically view the obstacle data from the costmap and make sure that it lines up with both the map and laser scans as I drive the robot around under joystick control. This is a sanity check that sensor data is making it into the costmap in a reasonable way. If I've decided to track unknown space with a robot, mostly these are robots that are using the `voxel_grid` model for the costmap, I make sure to look at the unknown space visualization to see that unknown space is being cleared out in a reasonable way. A good check I do to see if obstacles are being cleared out correctly from the costmap is to simply walk in front of the robot and see if it both successfully sees me and clears me out. For details on the topics published by the costmap to rviz, check out the [navigation with rviz tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack).
- Its a good idea to check the system load when the navigation stack is running only the costmap. This means bringing up the `move_base` node, but not sending it a goal and looking at load. If the computer is bogged down at this point, I know I need to make some CPU saving parameter tweaks if I want any chance of running the planners.

### Step 3: The Local Planner

If I'm satisfied that things up through the costmap are behaving satisfactorily, I'll move on to tuning parameters for the local planner. On robots that have reasonable acceleration limits, I typically use the [dwa_local_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dwa_local_planner), on those that have lower acceleration limits and would benefit from a rollout that takes acceleration limits into account at every step, I'll use the [base_local_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner)
. Tuning the dwa_local_planner is more pleasant than tuning the base_local_planner because its parameters are dynamically_reconfigurable, though adding dynamic_reconfigure across the board for the navigation stack is on the roadmap. Ok, on to tips for the planners:

- The most important thing for both planners is that the acceleration limit parameters are set correctly for a given robot. If these parameters are off, I'd expect sub-optimal behavior from a robot. If I don't know what the acceleration limits of a robot are, I'll take the time to write a script that commands max translational and rotational velocity to the motors for some period of time, look at the reported velocity from odometry (assuming the odometry gives a reasonable estimate of this), and derive the acceleration limits from that. Setting these parameters reasonably often saves me a lot of time later.
- If the robot I'm working with has low acceleration limits, I make sure that I'm running the base_local_planner with `dwa` set to false. After setting `dwa` to `true`, I'll also make sure to update the `vx_samples` parameter to something between 8 and 15 depending on the processing power available. This will allow for non-circular curves to be generated in the rollout.
- If localization for the robot I'm working with isn't great, I'll make sure to set the goal tolerance parameters a bit higher than I would otherwise. I'll also up the rotational tolerance if the robot has a high minimum rotational velocity to avoid oscillations at the goal point.
- If I'm using a low resolution for CPU reasons, I'll sometimes up the `sim_granularity` parameter a bit to save some cycles.
- I actually rarely find myself changing the `path_distance_bias` and `goal_distance_bias` parameters on the planners very much. When I do, its normally because I'm trying to restrict the freedom of the local planner to leave the planned path to work with a global planner other than [NavFn](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navfn). Turning the `path_distance_bias` parameter up, will make the robot follow the path more closely at the expense of moving towards the goal quickly. If this weight is set too high, the robot will refuse to move because the cost of moving is greater than staying at its location on the path.
- If I want to reason about the cost function in an intelligent way, I'll make sure to set the `meter_scoring` parameter to true. This makes it so distances in the cost function are in meters instead of cells and also means that I can tune the cost function for one map resolution and expect reasonable behavior when I move to others. Furthermore, you can now visualize the cost function produced by the local planner in rviz by setting the `publish_cost_grid` parameter to `true`. (This somehow never made it into the docs, I'll get to that sometime soon). Given the cost function in meters, I can compute the tradeoff in cost of moving 1 meter towards the goal balanced against how far away I am from the planned path. This tends to give me a decent idea of how to tune things.
- Trajectories are scored from their endpoints. This means that setting the `sim_time` parameter to different values can have a large affect on how the robot behaves. I normally set this parameter to between 1-2 seconds, where setting it higher can result in slightly smoother trajectories, making sure that the minimum velocity multiplied by the sim_period is less than twice my tolerance on a goal. Otherwise, the robot will prefer to rotate in place just outside of range of its target position rather than moving towards the goal.
- Accurate trajectory simulation also depends on having reasonable velocity estimates from odometry. This comes from the fact that both the dwa_local_planner and base_local_planner use this velocity estimate, along with the acceleration limits of the robot, to determine the feasible velocity space for a planning cycle. Though the velocity estimate coming from odometry doesn't have to be perfect, it is important to make sure that its at least close to get optimal behavior.

OK... that's basically what I've got off the top of my head. I might come back later and add to this, but, hopefully, this gives some insight into the nuances of tuning navigation.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 27

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-04-28**:
Eitan, thanks a lot for this guide. I would have one more interrogation though: Could you explain if the base controllers are strongly depending on accurate instantaneous speeds (twist part of twist messages)?

**Comment by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on 2011-04-28**:
Should this type of "howto" live on the ros.org wiki?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-26**:
Regarding the "publish_cost_grid" parameter: Indeed it never did make it into the docs. Oops. For reference, the original ticket with info is here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4620 . @eitan, do you know if the rviz patch (#4610) ever got released into the Debian builds?

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-05-28**:
Hello, I know I'm 4 years late but I performed the in-place rotation test and my result is this: [link text](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nfk7golkvpi6l1p/odom%20test%20with%20laser%20in%20place%20rotation.png?dl=0) Is this good or bad? I don't think it's very good odometry. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, from the video, it looks like mojo never actually achieves its goal position to perform an in-place rotation. Likely this is because you've got the sim_time parameter set to 5 seconds with a minimum velocity of 0.1 meters/second. Trajectory rollout scores trajectories based on their endpoints which means that any trajectory with positive x velocity will move at least 0.5 meters forward. So, when the robot gets close to the goal, in-place rotations and trajectories that take long arcs towards the goal will score higher than the straight line path that goes too far past the goal. I'd suggest turning sim_time down to something like 1.0 or 1.5 seconds. Also, this will likely mean you can turn your path_distance_bias parameter down a bit and still get reasonable behavior. If you have the CPU, I might also up the vx_samples since you're using trajectory rollout rather than dwa and will benefit from additional sampling in the x velocity space, perhaps something in the 8-10 range. Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20747/tixiao/) on 2017-05-09**:
I think this is the correct answer.